# How to change the text color of one cell based on text in another group of cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am having difficulties being able to change the color of text in a particular cell based on what is written in a different group of cells. Ex. The text in `E8` is to change to green if that exact text is found in any one of the cells in `F3:F5`.
I have been able to do this for individual cells `=SEARCH("text"$F$3)` but I am having trouble writing for a group of cells. 
Do I need to have 3 separate rules for this one cell? or is there a way to only have one rule?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting.  The rule you want to create is:

```
=COUNTIF($F$3:$F$5,"text")
```

<sub>(Note: This is not case sensitive)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Provided you really only want this for a single cell, a slightly shorter formula:

```
=COUNTIF(F3:F5,E8)
```

to be applied by selecting E8, clearing any exiting CF from it and and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:** *as above*, then <kbd>Format...</kbd>, select green fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.