# VBA search for values and delete from list (for loop is too slow)

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, search, delete-row

I get an Excel document sent each week with a list of employees that haven't completed training for a new IT-system we're getting. However, the training is not relevant for everyone, so I need to clean up in order to get the real numbers.

I have made a list of the employees which training is not relevant for (Oprydning), and use the following code to search for one name at a time and delete from the other list (Datagrundlag).

```
Private Sub RydOpKnap_Click()
Dim OprydningAntal As Long
Dim DataAntal As Long
Dim Find As String

Worksheets("Datagrundlag - endelig").Visible = True

OprydningsAntal = Worksheets("Oprydning").UsedRange.Rows.Count
DataAntal = Worksheets("Datagrundlag - endelig").UsedRange.Rows.Count

  Dim r, s As Long
    For r = 2 To OprydningsAntal
        Find = Worksheets("Oprydning").Cells(r, 1).Value
            For s = 2 To DataAntal


                If Worksheets("Datagrundlag - endelig").Cells(s, 3).Value = Find Then
                    Worksheets("Datagrundlag - endelig").Cells(s, 3).EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
            End If
            Next s
    Next r

    Worksheets("Datagrundlag - endelig").Visible = False

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

This takes forever though, since the list of not-relevant employees is currently 460 different values (and will get bigger). Is there another way to do this? I'm quite new to VBA, but would it be possible to use an array? Does the "Command Button" that initiates the code, make it slower?

Thanks in advance!

Heidi

Comment: Create an array from your current list of non-relevant staff and use it to AutoFilter with xlFilterValues. Delete visible rows and remove filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array from your current list of non-relevant staff and use it to AutoFilter with xlFilterValues. Delete visible rows and remove filter.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub RydOpKnap_Click()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    ReDim notRelevant(0) As Variant

    With Worksheets("Oprydning")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            ReDim Preserve notRelevant(i-2)
            notRelevant(i - 2) = .Cells(i, "A").Value
        Next i
    End With

    With Worksheets("Datagrundlag - endelig")
        .Visible = True

        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=(notRelevant), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        .Visible = False
        .Parent.RefreshAll
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the code. I was kind of struggling with how to set it up. What does the Option Explicit do? I get an error saying that the Method Delete for the Range class failed. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Option Explicit forces you to declare all variables. It will take me a little while to set up a full text bench.

Comment: Ah I see! Okay, thank you. I also kinda wanna try to fix it on my own :-) Thank you so so so much for the help!

Comment: My bad. I was trying to offset down 1 row on a full column. I've adjusted it above.

Comment: Hot damn, it works! And takes like 3 seconds. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another way to do this?

Yes, use Conditional Formatting to colour those to be excluded [eg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407789/how-to-change-the-text-color-of-one-cell-based-on-text-in-another-group-of-cells/52408708#52408708), and filter to delete the rows with formatted cells.

[image: SO53707228 example]

Comment: Interesting! Wouldn't I also have to use an array to find the names of the not-relevant staff and colour them?